# MySQL query to count results greater than 10 then group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, having-clause

I have a MySQL table named **water_test**. Within this table I have an **id**, a **province**, and a **sample_result**.

```
| id | province | sample_result |
| 1  | prov_1   | 3             |
| 2  | prov_2   | 12            |
| 3  | prov_3   | 45            |
| 4  | prov_4   | 7             |
| 5  | prov_2   | 8             |
| 6  | prov_2   | 76            |
| 7  | prov_3   | 32            |
| 8  | prov_1   | 5             |
| 9  | prov_1   | 99            |
| 10 | prov_4   | 67            |
| 11 | prov_2   | 4             |
```

I would like to find all sample_results greater than 10 for each province.

The query result should look like this...

```
| province | count |
| prov_1   | 1     |
| prov_2   | 2     |
| prov_3   | 2     |
| prov_4   | 1     |
```

How would you express this in a MySQL query? I was thinking GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT and tried this...

```
SELECT sample_result
  FROM water_test
 GROUP BY province
HAVING COUNT(sample_result) > 10;
```

but for this query fails to run (error 1055).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter, then aggregate:

```
select province, count(*)
from mytable
where sample_result > 10
group by province
```

Comment: I've run this query and it works perfectly. Thanks for you're help GMB

Comment: In this query the province which have no records with `sample_result > 10` will not be listed at all. If you need such province to be listed with zero count use another technique.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum conditionally like this

```
SELECT province, sum(sample_result > 10) as count
FROM water_test
GROUP BY province
```